# How to remove lines in file if variable substring match

Tags: batch-file

we've implemented a code that, starting from a particular csv, extract specific column and put them in another csv:

There is some possibility to remove line that starting in a particular position (the `,` is a separator) with a specific character? We've tried to associate an `if` statement using this:

```
(   for /f "tokens=6,13 delims=|" %%a in (to_be.csv) do %%a,%%b >FROM_IMPORT.csv
    for /f "tokens=2" %%a in (FROM_IMPORT.csv) do (set line=%%a
        if %line=='A' findstr /v %line FROM_IMPORT.csv> test.csv)
```

so the output for `FROM_IMPORT.csv` is `Site1, ALondon` for the first line, and `Site2, CLondon` is the second line –

It doesn't work, someone has a solution for that?

Comment: the code is:"(for /f "tokens=6,13 delims=|" %%a in (to_be.csv) do %%a,%%b >FROM_IMPORT.csv
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in (FROM_IMPORT.csv) do (set line=%%a
if %line=='A' findstr /v  %line FROM_IMPORT.csv> test.csv)"     so the output for FROM_IMPORT.csv is Site1, ALondon for the first line, and Site2, CLondon is the second line

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add a [mcve] there.  Avoid posting code snippets in comments.

Comment: Hi Josefz, in our case, we've a csv file (example FROM_IMPORT.csv) with field separated by comma. What we try to do,it's to generate another csv  (OUT.csv) excluding from FROM_IMPORT.csv file all the lines having the third field starting with a specific string (for example, TEST).  Example: FROM_IMPORT.csv contains in first line Sitea, TESTLOCATION, London and in second line Siteb, PRODLOCATION, London; what we need to do, it's excluding the first line, because contains TEST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code snippet could help:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
REM (
REM   for /f "tokens=6,13 delims=|" %%a in (to_be.csv) do echo %%a,%%b
REM )>FROM_IMPORT.csv
(
  for /f "tokens=1,* delims=," %%a in (FROM_IMPORT_58702269.csv) do (
     set "line=%%b"
     if /I NOT "!line:~0,4!"=="TEST" echo %%a,%%b
  )
)>test_58702269.csv
```

**Output**:

```
type test_58702269.csv
```

> ```
> The system cannot find the file specified.
> ```

```
type FROM_IMPORT_58702269.csv
```

> ```
> Sitea,TESTLOCATION,London
> Siteb,PRODLOCATION,London
> SiteC,TESTLOCATION,London
> SiteD,TESTLOCATION,London
> SiteE,PRODLOCATION,London
> ```

```
D:\bat\SO\58702269.bat
type test_58702269.csv
```

> ```
> Siteb,PRODLOCATION,London
> SiteE,PRODLOCATION,London
> ```

**Resources** (required reading, incomplete):

- [Variables: extract part of a variable (substring)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)
- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Shell How-To guides and examples](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- [(special page) Redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)
- [(special page) EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)